# Angularjs - App.js dir location same with angular?

Tags: angularjs, module

quick question, kinda dumb. Let's say you have your web app with an index.html and app.js where you want to place all your angularjs modules. Does the app.js need to be located to the same place the angular library is?
Or it doesn't actually matter since you will be loading both angularjs and your app.js at the index.html?

app.js would contain something like:
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

Is the message var app undefined just a matter of letting js know that this var is a global var?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. You just include the correct script source paths in the `script` tags.

Comment: So the var app undefined is just a matter of letting js know that this var is a global var? Do you remember the directive that says, this var is defined elsewhere, in order to suppress some warnings I get?

Comment: I meant angular undefined, sorry.